# Monitoring a particular sidekiq queue in a rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, sidekiq-monitor

As per the documentation for sidekiq monitoring at https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Monitoring if we need to monitor the queue backlog we add the following to `config/routes.rb`

```
require 'sidekiq/api'
match "queue-status" => proc { [200, {"Content-Type" => "text/plain"}, [Sidekiq::Queue.new.size < 100 ? "OK" : "UHOH" ]] }, via: :get
```

To monitor the latency

`match "queue-latency" => proc { [200, {"Content-Type" => "text/plain"}, [Sidekiq::Queue.new.latency < 30 ? "OK" : "UHOH" ]] }, via: :get`

**Q1.** I have multiple queues in my application called order_submission, mailers, critical and default. 
If i want to monitor the backlog or latency for a particular queue say 'order_submission' how can i do that ?

**Q2.** The documentation also says that `We have a Pingdom check every minute which fires off an email if the response == 'UHOH'` for the following

`match "queue-status" => proc { [200, {"Content-Type" => "text/plain"}, [Sidekiq::Queue.new.size < 100 ? "OK" : "UHOH" ]] }, via: :get`

I know the Pingdom service is used to hit urls for testing performance and availability but its not clear to me what it means that there is already a pingdom check that runs every minute and sends the email . Would like to have clarification on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**A1** You [may pass queue name](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/lib/sidekiq/api.rb#L211):

```
Sidekiq::Queue.new('my_queue').size
```

**A2** I didn't work with Pingdom, so I can just advise to:

1. Check their docs, whether they can parse response or not.
2. Change responce status when queque status is **not** OK, choose one [from the list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to monitor individual queue in sidekiq, you can do so with the help of [**sidekiq_queue_metrics**](https://github.com/ajitsing/sidekiq_queue_metrics) gem. It provides below features:

- View stats of all the queues
- View summary of an individual queue
- View failures of an individual queue along with backtrace.

Also the number of failures per queue is configurable.

Here is how you use this gem.

```
require 'sidekiq_queue_metrics'

Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  Sidekiq::QueueMetrics.init(config)
end
```

[**Also I have written a blog on this rubygem.**](http://www.singhajit.com/monitoring-individual-queue-in-sidekiq) Head over there for more details.

[image]